# How to use Azure Mobile Services practically (cross-platform client)?

Tags: c#, rest, mobile, azure, xamarin

Azure Mobile seems to be very useful having built-in common functions so I don't have to implement them myself. But still I can't understand how can use it if I need something more than the very simple example with ToDoItems. First of all TableController by one hand seems to be very useful 'cause it can provide persistent server features and client notification feautures. By other hand I can't understand how the example can be used for real mobile devices if the ToDoItem class is in the back-end assembly (of course I would like to include it in a mobile application). But if I use some shared assembly that has to be portable how can I implement ITableData if it is not in the portable subset? What is the way to use MobileServiceCollection with CollectionChanged event in some real project? Then the problem is how to implement the logic layer - the persitent mode with DbContext is good, but sometimes I need some more logical features on the server than just a storage. Scheduled jobs seem to don't suite cause I need to invoke some data processing by client data update but not by some schedule.

If somebody knows how to use Azure Mobile Services for a real project please give me some examples/ideas how a portable service layer for mobile applications can interact with Azure Mobile Services backend. For the client applications I use Xamarin tools.

Answer (score 1):

Utilising Xamarin means you can work entirely in C# so you can re-use many concepts you would know from developing C# solutions on non-mobile platforms.  For instance, you can share "DTOs" which means you can share code amongst all your platforms.  See: http://blog.siliconvalve.com/2013/08/16/portable-azure-mobile-services-dtos-when-using-xamarin-and-c/

I presented at TechEd Australia last year on this and the sample code is available on Github also.  A video of the talk and the sample link can be found here: http://blog.siliconvalve.com/2013/09/08/teched-demo-video-available-online/.

At launch mobile services utilised Node.js for server-side functionality (it is still supported) and it is now possible to develop server-side scripts using C# as well.  These aren't limited to just database interactions (though these tend to be the examples used).  If you look at my sample project you'll see I do some parsing of inbound data to fire off push notifications.

Ultimately there's no easy answer other than to start working with the code (you an run an Azure trial for free for a short period - more than enough to get familiar with the environment).

Comment: Thank you for the information about DTOs, they really work but I still don't understand how - does it determine classes correposndances just by their names without mapping at all? Also I've understand that TableController has virtual methods for Update, Insert etc. I can use them in logic, but I have one doubt - where are transaction scopes? I've not found yet a distinct answer but I need a true persistent server.

Comment: About DTOs I've just found a [good tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/05/19/mapping-between-database-types-and-client-type-in-the-net-backend-using-automapper.aspx). The TableController problem is still open for me.

Answer (score 0):

TableController is only supposed to provide a REST API for one type of entity.  At the root, REST is simple.  You've got ToDoList, ToDoListItem and maybe for each ToDoListItem you have multiple ToDoListListItemDetail entries.  This represents a one-to-many relationship between 3 entities.

Generated Table controllers only deal with one entity so scaffolding will create a ToDoListController for ToDoList entity, a ToDoListItemController for ToDoListItem and a ToDoListItemDetailController for ToDoListItemDetail entity.  But all of the entities that you have defined in your web app share the same Context and thus all of them can be queried in any of the controllers.  So while by default you can only do GET /tables/ToDoListItem which will give you all ToDoListItems or you can do GET /tables/ToDoListItem/{key} which will give you a specific ToDoListItem matching the key, you cannot get a ToDoListItem that matches a specific ToDoList.

As per REST best practices, such retrieval would be accomplished with GET /tables/ToDoList/{key}/ToDoListItem which would provide all ToDoListItems associated with a specific ToDoList identified by the key.  Now this belongs logically to the ToDoListController and in order to expand the controller to get this, you need to implement attribute based routing.

```
[RoutePrefix("tables/todolist")]
public class ToDoListController : TableController<DataObjects.ToDoList>
{
   ...
   // extended endpoint
   // GET tables/todolist/{key}/todolistitem
   [Route("{id:guid}/todolistitem")]
   public IQueryable<DataObjects.ToDoListItem> GetAllToDoListItemsForToDoList(string id)
   {
      return from l in Context.ToDoLists 
      join li in Context.ToDoListItems on l.Id equals li.ToDoListId
      where l.Id.Equals(id)
      select li;
   }
```

So now using this technique, you can query for whatever you want beyond basic entities provided by scaffolded Table controllers.

Now since you web API back end has to have it DataObject classes inherit from EntityData, you may not be able to reuse them entirely in your Xamarin app.  Your Xamarin app layer does not have to implement all data elements of EntityData either - probably only Id and Version.  But even if you had to duplicate the definition of your DataObjects (back-end) or DTOs/Models (client) its very small duplication.

If you need to call end points unrelated to table storage, you can invoke custom API as described in the **Work with a custom API** section of this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#work-with-tables).

I am not sure if I answered some of your questions or not so please provide more detail.